# asp.net mvc 4 controller execute multiple ajax calls in parallel

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have an asp.net MVC 4 controller thats methods are called via ajax.

The problem is that the ajax requests are handled sequentially by the controller.
This causes performance issues as the time to load the page is the sum of all ajax requests and not the longest ajax request.

To demonstrate this, I put a break point in the first ("ReadOverview8Week") method.
Each of these methods take ~600ms to execute individuality.

[image]

How can I make the controller respond to all three requests in parallel?
I am using iis 8.

This is the ajax request (from kendo ui dataSource)

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
   .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAllSitesOverview", "AbuseCase").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Include the code for your ajax requests.

Comment: The ajax requests in this example were from a kendo datasource.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue you are facing is caused by the way ASP.NET is managing session. Here is the most important part from [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) (*Concurrent Requests and Session State* section):

> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished.

You can resolve your issue if your actions doesn't require access to session. If that is the case, you can decorate the controller with [SessionStateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```

This way the controller will not have to wait for session.

If your actions require only read access to session, you can try using the `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` value. This will not result in an exclusive lock but the request will still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request.

Comment: Putting this on the controller fix my issue! Thank you.

Comment: How to do this in web api. I noticed ih I hit api multiple times in short period of times they are executed much much slower.

Comment: @vlado If you are using ASP.NET Web API the problem is the same (it doesn't affect self host). The only way to change it is through web.config. Also making sure your methods are async helps a bit.

Comment: it helps a bit althought data access is synchronous?  I thought ajax request are totaly independent on each other. I still didn't find simple explanation why async request are not totaly "async" and why async web api method helps if the requests are already asnyc(independent on each other).

Comment: @Vlado AJAX requests are "async" from browser point of view, not the server. On the server all request are the same and in context of ASP.NET web application session is a synchronization root unless you disable it. Making ApiController method async (and by this I mean not just putting async keyword in front of it, but also using async methods to accessing database etc) results in the method not blocking the thread while waiting for external resources - it helps a bit ;). I suggest we continue this discussion via email if you want, in order not to spam the comments.

Comment: Yeah Finally!! that's it. I Had lot's of Kendo component on my page getting data from Controller and the binding one by one gets on nerves . Thanks for your wisdom

Comment: I used "SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly", but its not working!

Comment: @DheerajKumar Can you be more precise about whta is not working? As stated in the answer `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` is not a perfect solution. It might help but doesn't have to (as it still have to wait for all write locks to be released).

Comment: @tpeczek thank you. Can you tell me if I make a call to web api controller which is stateless, in between of multiple calls to MVC controllers, do  API call have to wait for release of lock, Or it will complete it's request without any blocking. My assumption is it doesn't need to wait since it is session less, but when I tried it, it is waiting in queue just like MVC calls.

Comment: @DheerajKumar By default ApiControlles (I'm assuming by API calls you mean ASP.NET Web API) do not require session, so they should not block. But there are ways to make them require session (even globally) so it might happen that somebody enabled it in different place. This scenario would require a repro project to discuss in details.