# ASP.NET: Multiple ajax requests in short period of time are much slower

Tags: asp.net

I know there is some number of request each user of the application can execute at the time, and this number is big enough. Also, I thought ajax request are completely async. There is also number of requests browser can handle at time, but this number is 6 or more. I realize this: if I call my ASP.NET web api services "gently" meaning I call one method than wait a little bit then click again  they execute for about 200ms,300ms (other details are not important, so please don't ask to send the code, question is general and I noticed this behavoir in asp.net asmx services, WCF...) This is what is important: If I call this services "faster" (for example I call `mywebsite.com/api/results?page=1` than almost immediately `mywebsite.com/api/results?page=2` etc. they start to execute much slower (2,3,4 seconds) (that is 20 times slower). My question is: what is "not async" in "asnyc" request? The more async response I try to get they are slower to execute.

Comment: Maybe time needed to execute the request for page grows with the page number?
Try to execute `mywebsite.com/api/results?page=10` as a *first* request and see how long it takes.

Comment: No, this was just an example of some URL. What is important here is something else what I described .

Comment: The `not async` in `async` request might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549519/asp-net-mvc-4-controller-execute-multiple-ajax-calls-in-parallel